# How do I remove characters from a string at a certain position?

Tags: perl, substring

I have the variables `$pos`, `$toRemove` and `$line`. I would like to remove from this string `$toRemove` from position `$pos`.

```
$line = "Hello kitty how are you kitty kitty nice kitty";
$toRemove = "kitty";
$pos = 30; # the 3rd 'kitty'
```

I want to check if from position 30 there is string `kitty` and I want to remove exactly this one.

Could you give me a solution of that? I can do it using a lot of loops and variables but it looks strange and works really slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (substr($line, $pos, length($toRemove)) eq $toRemove) {
    substr($line, $pos, length($toRemove)) = "";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$line = "Hello kitty how are you kitty kitty nice kitty";
$toRemove = "kitty";
$pos = 30; # the 3rd 'kitty'

pos($line) = $pos;
$line =~ s/\G$toRemove//gc;
print $line;
```

output:

```
Hello kitty how are you kitty  nice kitty
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:

```
$line = "Hello kitty how are you kitty kitty nice kitty";
$toRemove = "kitty";
$pos = 30;

$line =~ s/(.{$pos})$toRemove/$1/;
print $line;
```

result:

```
Hello kitty how are you kitty  nice kitty
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$line =~ s/^.{30}\K$toRemove//;
```

This uses a look-behind assertion to match the first 30 characters without including them in the part of the pattern that is replaced.

Answer (score 1):

The [`pos`][pos] operator is an lvalue for just this sort of thing:

[pos]:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = "Hello kitty how are you kitty kitty nice kitty";
my $toRemove = "kitty";
my $pos = 30;

pos($line) = $pos;

$line =~ s/\G$toRemove//;

print $line;
```

**output**

```
Hello kitty how are you kitty  nice kitty
```